# PHP image resize with GD

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, gd

So I am working on an upload script (this is my first experience in PHP), and I have come across a problem:

Upload works correctly, the file gets uploaded to '../images/' than gets renamed to the mysql ID.
Once that is done I would like to resize the image to 96px x 96px. Than the problem starts:

I do have GD installed correctly (tested with a script), and here is my "resize" code:

```
$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/$newname");
$sm_image = Imagecreate(96,96);
Imagecopyresized($sm_image,$orig_image,0,0,0,0,50,50,imagesx($orig_image),imagesy($orig_image));
imageJPEG($sm_image);
```

The reslult I get is not a resized image, the image file is the exact same, but I do get:

```
RÃ©ussiÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC       $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ``"ÿÄ   ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ     ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á  #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?ðØãÍYK}Ýªh"Éé]6‹¥B¢;Ë¦M§%bqôÇ×9¯>¾!SWgÔá0Ö¹‘iáûÛÑ˜-Ý†3é‘ê3Ö¤“ÃW‘Åæ4nHÈ ôëÒ½ÍÞpÐ[4~n îRÆ:€~ƒÚ¢¹žrbV,O žyFqŒcvéŸzò´*¹ZÈõ–ŠÑ£Ë®,ŠŽeË    Bx¯HÕ¬âž2èŒ²©çqáò2ñ÷®>þØuƒ^®Îµ<œÇ+Š‹œAÒ–œëµÈ#Úôœµ´ (¢Q@N›n.."‰†UœnÇËÔóÛŒ×|ó[,o¹ŒoŒ°øSÓë\.™(‚D”…<çÐŒç]m»\_Û—´¼Æh‹$c®O9Á==}>s›’od}ö)SL œ‘ÜK4xGb´}Kìù³ô Ÿò+AnæOÜ„SI½U;rFpO$ƒƒž¤˜¬‹†¸³VØ²Jd ácÂ°n€8Ïõïšµ é¹“ÊXæg9@™Þ¨§9À8ãon•É8I¤Þ¦îÌ•ü©'Øˆ©FeG'°àçƒùŒ’Er:ý´+©O¢±ˆ¶PHÏ8üë§û@0•XÊü¡¦’ry°{qšlí´»{SSlÌü[B3¸Œ`ç¦oÀãµkBn”¯øw"¬T£fyü oxñ?ÞIöÈúÕj¹ªÌ×”Ò±Éb?ªuôÔïÈ®|!%Zj;]þaEU˜…Q@>z‘Œ0‚=«®ÐutFrÊÞx‘6õ|ƒÎîÇÿ­é^e ÑCZ0ê3Çzòñ8?h™õx<Òœ £3Ò Žæò%–u+3LÏ2Œ”q’ON„c¸Ï"­K$«t³Fö±Èîùjw‡+‚1Æ}xõõâ¸[oÞ[¬j$"}êæÁçüMMqâÛé”(tˆàE¯_p3^d°5œºXôþ³IësPÕ`µÛ@O›&w;Ôã9ãõÈ®sXÕ¥»|¼ŒÄn,IosšÍ¸Ô¤˜îfÉ¬ù®wµÝ‡Á¨Y½ÎLN>œbÔJWGuËŸ§ò¨iÎw94Úö²>>¤¹¦ßvQE2Š( À§‡aÐÓh iÛbA4ƒø¨óåþ÷éQÑK•í'Ý’yÒ{ô¦cÔÒQEœä÷aES$(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢ŠÿÙ
```

Any tips on getting this to work ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you set your header correctly?

Comment: So i have added the header, now I just get an empty image, the html links to the scrpt (<img src="uploaded.php">) -> See lower answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to add `headers`

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

Since you want 96x96 it should be:

```
imagecopyresized($sm_image,$orig_image,0,0,0,0,96,96,imagesx($orig_image),imagesy($orig_image));
```

Comment: So i have added the header, now I just get an empty image, the html links to the scrpt (<img src="uploaded.php">)

Comment: you know that script only re-sizes the image temporary? You should save it in order to use it later `imagejpeg($sm_image, $path, $quality);`

Comment: Yes, this worked great ! The image does resize and saves, but the ratio seems completely different, I have tried with an image 740x740 and the small version isn't at all the same thing, any clew for that ?

Comment: Got it working with sm_image = imagecreatetruecolor(96,96); => Better image quality, thanks for your help !